# How to dynamically add columns and group by NULL's in MySQL Pivot?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with values of name and occupation. I am trying to do 2 things

1. Pivot the table (achieved)
2. Dynamically add / remove columns based on the values
3. Reduce the NULL values in columns after pivot

My query:

```
select Actor, Teacher, Doctor from (
SELECT
(case when occupation = (select distinct occupation from occs a order by 1 limit 0,1) then name else NULL end) as "Actor"
,(case when occupation = (select distinct occupation from occs a order by 1 limit 1,1) then name else NULL end) as "Teacher"
,(case when occupation = (select distinct occupation from occs a order by 1 limit 2,1) then name else NULL end) as "Doctor"
FROM occs order by 1) x ;
```

Output of above query:

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| Actor | Teacher | Doctor |
+-------+---------+--------+
| NULL  | NULL    | ketty  |
| NULL  | Jane    | NULL   |
| NULL  | Zhan    | NULL   |
| julia | NULL    | NULL   |
| meera | NULL    | NULL   |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

I am trying to get Output as

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| Actor | Teacher | Doctor |
+-------+---------+--------+
| julia | Jane    | ketty  |
| meera | Zhan    | NULL   |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

Additionally in my sql I am specifying the columns Actor, Teacher, Doctor.
Is there a way that I could scan the table ans get the columns without having to manually do a distinct.

DDL/DML for problem:

```
CREATE TABLE occs (
  name varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  occupation varchar(10));


insert into occs values ('julia','Actor');
insert into occs values ('meera','Actor');
insert into occs values ('ketty','Teacher');
insert into occs values ('Jane','Doctor');
insert into occs values ('Zhan','Doctor');
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 8.0 MySQL version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query that will give you your desired results. It uses a CTE to create a table of names and occupations and their row number within their occupation. It then uses conditional aggregation to build the output table, grouping the CTE results on the row number:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT name, occupation, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation) AS rownum
FROM occs)
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'Actor' THEN name END) AS Actor,
    MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'Teacher' THEN name END) AS Teacher,
    MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'Doctor' THEN name END) AS Doctor
FROM cte
GROUP BY rownum
```

Output:

```
Actor   Teacher Doctor
julia   ketty   Jane
meera   null    Zhan
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kPkc5A9zfL6P7kU3thASRD/0)

To avoid having to specify the column names, you would need to use a stored procedure and create a dynamic SQL query.